# Silverlight ResourceDictionary not available

Tags: xaml, silverlight-4.0, resources

I've put a few good hours into this.. I'm unable to see the various styles I have defined in a global Resource dictionary.  The external file is called Styles.xaml.  What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things to consider using MergedDictionaries.

First you should set the BuildAction of the ResourceDictionary (Styles.xaml) to Resource or Content (I tried it with Resource).

Second in your App.xaml do not define a Key for the ResourceDictionary (remove x:Key="ButtonStyles")

Then put all other resources in your Application.Resources in the ResourceDictionary.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Assets/Styles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <CCE_2009_Client_ViewModels:ViewModelLocator x:Key=ViewModelLocatorDataSource/>

        <!-- Any additional resources -->
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

After all this is done then you should select the Style in the Properties Window.

Comment: I can't tell you how long I worked at this!  I had a working example but never realized that I also had to put my other global resources within an UNNAMED resource dictionary.  I'm assuming that if you name the resource dictionary you have to identify it from the various pages?  Why do they allow named resource dictionaries?

Thanks for th tip!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have referenced `CCE_2009.Client` assembly (project) in the project you want to use this style?

If not this can be a fix for your problem.